# How to Marshal data in a double-nested structure

Tags: c#, pinvoke, marshalling

The following code has been simplified, but embodies the general functionality.  It currently works with just `Struct1` and `Struct2`, but I need to add the third structure.  The issue is that the size of the third structure can vary over `i`.  What I have found is that as I step through the code, the data that gets passed into the C library contains only the initialized-to-zero value for my `dataStr`, instead of the `"Hello World 0.0"` value I assigned to it.

I've not been able to find a good example of how to do what I need to do.  Some thoughts/concerns/queries on my problem:

- Do I need to find `j` for all `i`, and allocate all of that memory first, then loop again to fill in the data?
- Where is the best place to free the memory allocated for `s2.pStruct3`?
- Is the freeing for `s1.pStruct2` in the right place (legacy code, which I always find suspect)?  There are cases where `i` > 1, and it seems to me like it would only free the final allocated block of memory, creating a memory leak.
- I am considering keeping a list of all of the allocated blocks of memory and then looping over the list at the end of the function to free in reverse order of allocation.  Is this the best approach?

TIA!

```
[StructLayout( LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1 )]
public struct Struct3 {
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 40)]
    public string dataStr;
}

[StructLayout( LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1 )]
public struct Struct2 {
    public int    numStruct3;
    public IntPtr pStruct3;
}

[StructLayout( LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1 )]
public struct Struct1 {
    public int    numStruct2;
    public IntPtr pStruct2;
}

public void MyFunc() {
    var sizeS1 = Marshal.SizeOf<Struct1>();
    var sizeS2 = Marshal.SizeOf<Struct2>();
    var sizeS3 = Marshal.SizeOf<Struct3>();

    var s1Ptr  = Marshal.AllocHGlobal( sizeS1 );
    var s1     = Marshal.PtrToStructure<Struct1>(s1Ptr);

    s1.numStruct2 = 1;
    s1.pStruct2   = Marshal.AllocHGlobal( sizeS2 * s1.numStruct2 );
    s1.pStruct2.Fill( 0, sizeS2 * s1.numStruct2 );

    IntPtr  s3Ptr;
    Struct3 s3;

    for( int i = 0; i < s1.numStruct2; ++i )
    {
        IntPtr s2Ptr = new IntPtr( s1.pStruct2.ToInt64() + ( i * sizeS2 ) );
        var    s2    = Marshal.PtrToStructure<Struct2>( s2Ptr );

        s2.numStruct3 = FindNumOfStruct2();
        s2.pStruct3   = Marshal.AllocHGlobal( s2.numStruct3 * sizeS3 );  // Doesn't get freed
        s2.pStruct3.Fill( 0, s2.numStruct3 * sizeS3 );

        for( uint j = 0; j < s2.numStruct3; ++j )
        {
            string data = String.Format( "Hello World #{0}.{1}", i, j );

            s3Ptr = new IntPtr( s2.pStruct3.ToInt64() + ( j * sizeS3 ) );
            s3    = Marshal.PtrToStructure<Struct3>( s3Ptr );

            s3.dataStr = data;
            Marshal.StructureToPtr<Struct3>( s3, s3Ptr, false );
        }

        Marshal.StructureToPtr<Struct2>( s2, s2Ptr, false );
    }

    Marshal.StructureToPtr<Struct1>( s1, s1Ptr, false );

    CallCFunction( CFacadeHandle, s1Ptr );

    Marshal.FreeHGlobal( s1.pStruct2 );
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal( s1Ptr );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are over-thinking this. The marshaller can automatically marshal arrays from C# to C, and can even do nested arrays. You only need to manually marshal it when the array is allocated in C, and the size of the array is not known before calling the function.

```cs
[StructLayout( LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1 )]
public struct Struct3
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 40)]
    public string dataStr;
}

[StructLayout( LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1 )]
public struct Struct2
{
    public int    numStruct3;
    public Struct3[] pStruct3;

    public Struct2(Struct3[] array)
    {
        pStruct3 = array;
        numStruct3 = array.Length;
    }
}

[StructLayout( LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1 )]
public struct Struct1
{
    public int    numStruct2;
    public Struct2[] pStruct2;

    public Struct1(Struct2[] array)
    {
        pStruct2 = array;
        numStruct2 = array.Length;
    }
}

public void MyFunc()
{
    var length1 = 1
    var s1 = new Struct1(new Struct2[length1]);
    for (int i = 0; i < length2; ++i)
    {
        var length2 = FindNumOfStruct2();
        s1.pStruct2[i] = new Struct2(new Struct3[length2]);
        for (int j = 0; j < length2; ++j )
        {
            string data = $"Hello World #{i}.{j}";
            s1.pStruct2[i].pStruct3[j] = new Struct3 { dataStr = data };
        }
    }

    CallCFunction(CFacadeHandle, ref s1);
}
```

I'm not sure why you set `Pack = 1` as it's non-standard. I hope y ou've checked that.

Your existing code had numerous issues anyway:

- You certainly didn't need to allocate the base `Struct1`, you can just use `ref`.
- You don't need to zero out the allocation, copy it out and copy back. You can just copy in once from a normal C# struct.
- Freeing the memory needs to happen in a loop i.e. you need to loop through the nested structs freeing all the pointers you allocated.
- The freeing needs to happen in a `finally`, in case of an exception, otherwise you could leak the memory.
- It is possible to allocate the memory on the C side, but then marshalling and freeing it is much harder. Allocating and freeing in C# is much easier if you are PInvoking.

Comment: What is `s1Ptr` in your solution?  If I try to pass `ref s1` then I get an error that "argument 2 may not be passed with the 'ref' keyword".  The structure must be passed as a pointer because the C function modifies the structure in place.

NOTE: This is NOT my code.  I just have to update it.  And IMO it's a mess.

Comment: Yes use `ref s1`. Change the PInvoke parameter to `ref Struct1 s1Ptr`. The marshaller will copy it out and back, you don't need to worry about that. You haven't shown that, nor the C function, so can't really help more.

Comment: The PInvoke parameter loses me - which is a spotlight for something I need to research and find in this code base!

Comment: Look for the declaration of `CallCFunction`, which should have a `[DllImport]` attribute.